# Removing final elements of a path to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the use case of needing to find the parent path of a sub path for which I have written the following function:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from os.path import sep


def pathbase(main, sub):
    if main.endswith(sub):
        parent = main[:-len(sub)]

        while parent.endswith(sep):
            parent = parent[:-1]

        return parent

    else:
        raise ValueError('Main path does not end on sub-path')


path1 = '/foo/bar/spamm/eggs'
path2 = 'spamm/eggs'

print(pathbase(path1, path2))
```

But I find that this is awfully verbose and that I re-invented the wheel with it. 
Also it breaks if the paths have an unequal amount of trailing slashes, so my method would need to normalize both paths first, which would make it even more verbose.
Is there already some library method which does that, that I may have overlooked?

**Edit:** Due to the problems regarding the undesired partial node-match mentioned in some answers and comments I refactored the method to this:

```
from os.path import basename, dirname, normpath


def pathbase(main, sub):
    """Extract basename of main
    relative to its sub-path sub
    """

    norm_main = normpath(main)
    norm_sub = normpath(sub)

    while basename(norm_main) == basename(norm_sub):
        norm_main = dirname(norm_main)
        norm_sub = dirname(norm_sub)
    else:
        if basename(norm_sub):
            raise ValueError('"{sub}" is not a sub-path of {main}'.format(
                sub=sub, main=main))

    return norm_main
```

Comment: What is the desired output? `'/foo/bar/'`? Take a look at [`os.path.relpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath).

Comment: What's that while for ?

Comment: @Daerdemandt: It would be ```/foo/bar``` in the example.
@Dex' ter: To normalize the path in a case like ```pathbase('/foo/bar////spamm/eggs', 'spamm/eggs')```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, have in mind what @Daerdemandt suggested in comments (using `os.path.relpath` - even though I think this is returning the matches but I might be wrong)

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath):

> Return a relative filepath to path either from the current directory
>   or from an optional start directory. This is a path computation: the
>   filesystem is not accessed to confirm the existence or nature of path
>   or start.
>
> start defaults to `os.curdir`.
>
> Availability: Unix, Windows.

After some reading of the `os` module, I don't think this is possible either. Sincerely, it is an *unusual* path manipulation which leads to the reason of not having it in the above mentioned module.

Apart from this, we can cut down you method and make it straight-forward:

```
import sys


def pathbase(path1, path2):
    try:
        if path1.endswith(path2):
            return path1[:-len(path2)]
        raise TypeError
    except TypeError:
        print('Main path does not end on sub-path')
        sys.exit(0)


path1 = '/foo/bar/spamm/eggs'
path2 = 'spamm/eggs'

print(pathbase(path1, path2))
```

There's not much to say about this. I just simplified your code by removing the `while` part which didn't make too much sense to me. I also removed the `else` part and `raise`d a `TypeError` which I used in an `try-except` block.

#### Some minor style things

- you could've call your method: `get_base_path()`
- you could've name your arguments: `main_path` and `sub_path`

In the end, everything would look just like:

```
import sys


def get_base_path(main_path, sub_path):
    try:
        if main_path.endswith(sub_path):
            return main_path[:-len(sub_path)]
        raise TypeError
    except TypeError:
        print('Main path does not end on sub-path')
        sys.exit(0)


main_path = '/foo/bar/spamm/eggs'
sub_path = 'spamm/eggs'

print(get_base_path(main_path, sub_path))
```

The above returns:

> `/foo/bar/`

Answer (score 3):

Your function doesn't behave the way I would expect: `pathbase('/foo/bar/spamm/eggs', 'mm/eggs')` would return `/foo/bar/spa` instead of raising `ValueError`.

I suggest the following solution.  It has a side-effect of normalizing the paths (as demonstrated in the fourth doctest below), but that's probably a good thing.

```
import os.path

def pathbase(main, sub):
    """
    Strip trailing path components.

    >>> pathbase('/foo/bar/spamm/eggs', 'spamm/eggs')
    '/foo/bar'
    >>> pathbase('/foo/bar/spamm/eggs', 'spam/eggs')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      ...
    ValueError: Main path does not end with sub-path
    >>> pathbase('/foo/bar/spamm/eggs', 'eggs')
    '/foo/bar/spamm'
    >>> pathbase('/foo/./bar/baz/../spamm/eggs', 'bar/soap/../spamm/eggs/')
    '/foo'
    """
    main = os.path.normpath(main)
    sub = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.sep, sub))
    if main.endswith(sub):
        return main[:-len(sub)]
    else:
        raise ValueError('Main path does not end with sub-path')
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `else` and keep only the `raise ValueError('Main path does not end with sub-path')` part